# How can i access only the specific textbox on clicking an icon next to it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can i access only the specific textbox on clicking an icon next to it. I know i have to use $this, but being new i am not able to make it.
help appreciated. :)

JS:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#plus').click( function(event) {
        if($('.abc').val() == ''){
            $('.abc').val(10);
        }else{
            $inc = parseInt($('.abc').val()) + 10;
            $('.abc').val($inc);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```html
<form class="chkform" id="chkform" name="chkform" method=post action="">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="abc" name="abc" value="">
<img src="plus.png" id="plus" name="plus" class="plus" >
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
</form>

<form class="chkform" id="chkform" name="chkform" method=post action="">
<input type="text" class="abc" id="abc" name="abc" value="">
<img src="plus.png" id="plus" name="plus" class="plus" ><img src="minus.png" id="minus" name="minus" class="minus">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code first?

Comment: here i want that when i click #plus only that textbox increments and not the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form isn't very well coded, you can't have duplicate IDs, which you have a few off.

I've changed the function to look for `.plus` and it now gets the input field that was before it and performs the actions on that instead of both:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.plus').click( function(event) {
        var textArea = $(this).prev('input[type="text"]');
        if(textArea.val() == ''){
            textArea.val(10);
        }else{
            $inc = parseInt(textArea.val()) + 10;
            textArea.val($inc);
        }
    });
});​
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/wQc8U/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('<yourselctor>').click(function(e) {
        var parent = $(this).closest('<parent container selector>');
        var target = parent.find('<your desired textbox selector>');
    });
});
```

In the *target* you can have your desired textbox.